# Share two TextView with one Button

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I have  two textview and i want to merge two textview and when i click to share button send data `latitude_textview` and `longitude_textview` together, how I can do it?

> For example,when i'm pressing to share button i want to get 21.00000, 21.00000 and share it.

```
        shareit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareit);
        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_textview));
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_textview));

        //share location button
        shareit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                TextView msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_textview);
                String finalMsg = String.valueOf(msg.getText().toString().trim());
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, finalMsg);
                Intent modIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Поделиться..");
                startActivity(modIntent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you copy the code here instead of having it in image form?

Comment: when you execute code what is the result

Comment: Check this [link](https://aatul.me/tag/code-for-passing-multiple-values-between-activities-in-android/) to see how to pass data between two activities

Comment: @ALTegani result it's sharing only this longitude_textview

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil can you explain me it on my code? what i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to

```
    mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_textview));
    mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_textview));

    //share location button
    shareit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            String lat = mLatitudeTextView.getText().toString();
            String lng = mLongitudeTextView .getText().toString();
            String finalMsg = "Lat : " + lat + ", Lon : "+ lng;
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, finalMsg);
            Intent modIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Поделиться..");
            startActivity(modIntent);
        }
    });
```

You can look more here : [Sending Simple Data](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just get text from those textviews and store them in a single string, then share that.

```
String lat = mLatitudeTextView.getText().toString();
String lng = mLongitudeTextView .getText().toString();
String latlng = lat + "\n" + lng;
```

Hope this is what you want.